# Calculate Field with Python Parser an If statements?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I don't know a whole lot about python and scripting, so I was hoping somebody could give me a couple pointers on fixing some code.  I am trying to calculate a "final results" attribute field.  The field type is numeric, because I want the values to either be a 1 (pass) or 0 (fail).  Below are two variations of the code I have tried, but they both give me errors.  The two fields I am trying to calculate from are both text fields, and the values for both are either "PASS" or "FAIL."[image]
[image]

Comment: What was the error? You also seem to be returning strings, not numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In general your condition statement should go as:

```
if TEST1 == 'FAIL':
    return 0
```

Single or double quotes for checking fields with string values, and when returning to a numeric field no quotes needed.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your logic correctly, if either Test1 or Test2 = FAIL, you want to return 0, but if both = PASS you want to return 1. I'd do something like this:

```
def Final(t1, t2):
    if t1 == 'FAIL' or t2 == 'FAIL':
        val = 0
    elif t1 == 'PASS' and t2 == 'PASS':
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 2   # this allows you to check if t1 or t2 had some other value
    return val
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) structure (`{key: value}`) to convert keywords like `PASS` to the standard bool type (i.e., `True` and `False`). After this conversion to bool, it is conventional logic:

```
def Final(t1, t2):
    c = {'PASS': True, 'FAIL': False}
    t1 = c[t1]
    t2 = c[t2]
    if t1 and t2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Note that if you have other test values like `GOOD` or `Pass`, you will see a KeyError, so you can extend the dict structure, if necessary, to other synonyms that are either `True` or `False`.